# How to serialize Json VB.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, rest

I am trying to call a rest service..that service returns json object...I am able to send the request but unable to serialize the json...here is the code i am trying

```
 Function Sendingrequest(Item As Object) As String


            Dim request As HttpWebRequest
            Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
            Dim res As StreamReader
            Try
                request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/SomeService/Type?id=" Item), HttpWebRequest)
                response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
                res = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
                Dim serializer As New System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(res.[GetType]())
                Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
                serializer.WriteObject(ms, res)
                Dim json As String = Encoding.[Default].GetString(ms.ToArray())
                Return json

            Finally
                If Not response Is Nothing Then response.Close()
            End Try


        End Function
```

I am not sure if i am passing the parameter correctly through the url...i hard coded the url to "http://localhost/SomeService/Type?id=ABC" then the url is hit but i am getting this error

Type 'System.Text.UTF8Encoding+UTF8Decoder' with data contract name 'UTF8Encoding.UTF8Decoder:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Text' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually hard to tell from just the detail you've provided where or what the problem is.

Here is what I suggest:

- Enable tracing on the service side, generate tracing logs, and analyze with SvcTraceViewer. To do this, follow the instructions at [this MSDN article on using the service trace viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx). Notice what's different between the first and second time.
- Turn on debug exceptions. This is done by turning in includeExceptionDetailInFaults, which [you can do by following the instructions here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/david_bennett/archive/2006/11/12/how-to-turn-on-debug-exceptions-with-wcf.aspx). Notice what's different between the first and second time.
- Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to monitor the wire traffic on both the client side and the service side.

Generally, once you do this, you should plenty of more info on what's going funky at the service side and can diagnose the issue pretty quickly. Try it, and please report back! :)